# Can I show a list of events with Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Currently on a web site that I help administer, we have a custom built calendar built with PHP. The web site is for a performance group, and they have various categories of performances. For simplicity, lets say they have two, dancing shows and singing shows.

We're considering switching to Google Calendar, in order to be able to share the calendar with other sites and other collaborative features that the service offers.

However, we don't want to lose the functionality we have now, mainly to do with how the calendar displays on the group's web site. There are three conditions which call for different calendar views.

1. One condition is the group's overall schedule, which is a standard
   view by calendar month. This is the default Google Calendar display
   option, so no problem there.
2. The other condition is to display the next 3 upcoming events by
   category. So on the dance events page, we want to see a list of the
   next three dance events. If I have the terminology right, this is an
   "agenda" view, but I'm not sure about that. So on this page the
   embedded calendar object would need to filter for just dance events.
   Similarly, on the singing page, the embedded calendar would need to
   filter for singing events.
3. The last condition is to show upcoming events of all types. So this
   would show the next 3 events of dance and singing together, in a
   list, ordered by date.

I am unclear on whether or not events can be categorized by type for filtering purposes, and if calendars can be displayed in a list style. I've seen mention of an "agenda" view, but I haven't been able to discern exactly how one enables it.

Are these requirements possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agenda view will help meet your conditions. To do so go to Google Calendar, in My Calendar there will be a cut down on your calendar click on it, then Calendar settings. There you will see "Customize the color, size, and other options" in "embed this calendar". There you would find the agenda view.

Besides that Google Calendars offers api's that can offer great customization.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Comment: anybody know what he means by a "cut down on your calendar" ?

Comment: @K.W.Crosby probably meant "dropdown".

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Updated description as of 2021, on desktop:

**To see it inside Google Calendar or Print:**

In dropdown menu button in the upper right corner (right next to the gear icon for the settings), you can select a "Schedule" view. Or simply press the hotkey "A" to activate it. [1]

To print this view, click the gear icon in the top right corner.

**To Embed or Print:**

Go to the Settings for a specific Calendar. Under "Integrate Calendar", click the "Customize" button. In the upper right corner, click "Agenda" or "Print".

[1] Update 2022-05-09:

If you don't see the dropdown in the upper right corner (right next to the settings gear icon), you can still swap between the Schedule Views with the following hotkeys:

| Schedule view | Hotkey |
| --- | --- |
| Day | D |
| Week | W |
| Month | M |
| Year | Y |
| Schedule | A |
| 7 days | X |

Comment: I don't see any dropdown menu any more :-( But pressing "A" works. But don't know how to get it back... I don't see any controls that would control this. It is a f***ing mess....

Comment: @Tomas Try clicking "W" for Week or "M" for Month, to go back. I also updated the answer with description of the other hotkeys, and clarification that the dropdown is in the upper right corner right next to the gear icon for the settings. You probably just overlooked it since it changed to say "Schedule" when you pressed "A". Hope the updated answer helps. :-)